# Vuetify $refs.form.reset and $refs.form.resetValidation giving errors

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When trying to do `this.$refs.form.reset()` or `this.$refs.form.resetValidation()` I get this error

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined"

I'm using it like this

```
<v-form
    ref="form"
    v-model="valid"
    lazy-validation
    style="padding: 20px">
    <v-row>
        <v-col>
            <v-text-field
                v-model="form.name"
                :rules="rules.name"
                :counter="10"
                label="Bank Name" required/>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</v-form>
```

And calling this method when the dialog where the form is, is clicked

```
createItem() {
    this.cancel();
    this.mode = "New Bank";
    this.dialog = true;
},
cancel() {
    this.dialog = false;
    this.$refs.form.reset()
},
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: are both on the same file?

Comment: @HansFelixRamos yea, all the above code is on the same page

Answer (score 3):

If the createItem() is called on the click of button which is used to open the dialog box. Then the this.$refs.form.reset() in the cancel() may be called before the form component is rendered. So one option would be to reset the form after the item is created, or you can use

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    if (this.$refs[form]) {
      this.$refs.form.reset();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's good! only one correction, i had to wrap the form name in quotes, like this: this.$refs['form'].  As explained before, this is because when the page is created, the form is not there yet, hence the error. later it works fine. so we only have to avoid the initial error.

Answer (score 2):

when you call "this.dialog = false;" the dialog may be not exist, so when you call "this.$refs.form.reset()" the "this.$refs.form" is undefined. the code should like this:

```
cancel() {
    this.$refs.form.reset()
    this.dialog = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DO this while opening the dialogue.

```
cancel() {
    this.$refs.form.reset()
    this.dialog =true;

},
```

Answer (score 1):

When opening a dialog containing a form with validation and calling `this.$refs.form.reset()` and/or `this.$refs.form.resetValidation()`

To avoid the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined"

An alternative approach, from the previous answers, is to use a watch on the dialog as follows:

```js
export default {
  name: "DialogFormResetExample",
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    formValid: false,
    form: {
      name: "",
    },
    nameRules: [
      (v) => !!v || 'Name is required',
      (v) => (v && v.length <= 10) || 'Name must be less than 10 characters',
    ],
  }),
  watch: {
    dialog(visible) {
      if (visible) {
        // Clear the form and reset the validation when the dialog is opening
        this.$refs.form.reset();
        this.$refs.form.resetValidation();
      } else {
        // Do stuff when the dialog is closing
      }
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog" eager persistent max-width="600px">
  
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" text> Open </v-btn>
    </template>
    
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        <span class="text-h5">Dialog Form Reset Example</span>
      </v-card-title>
      
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12">
              <v-form ref="form" v-model="formValid">
                <v-text-field
                  label="Name*"
                  v-model="form.name"
                  v-bind:rules="nameRules"
                  required
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-form>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
        <small>*indicates required field</small>
      </v-card-text>
      
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn text @click="dialog = false"> Cancel </v-btn>
        <v-btn text v-bind:disabled="!formValid"> Submit </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
    
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

**IMPORTANT!** Add the *[eager](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/)* prop to the dialog. This will force the dialog's content to render on mounted. Without it, the form and `this.$ref.form` will not exist, i.e. undefined; resulting in a similar error to the original error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "dialog": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but this trick works for me

```
this.$refs['form'].reset()
this.$refs['form'].resetValidation()
```